# SharePoint .aspx upload issue

Tags: sharepoint-online

I am having problems with getting `.aspx` files to be viewed in browsers on SharePoint Online. I have tried uploading by drag and drop and by choosing file upload. I have tried using I.E., Edge and Chrome browsers. I have even tried switching between classic and the modern view. The problem is when they are uploaded they are only available to download and I need them to be viewed on the web. I have Edit permissions and I have been told by the system admins that this is enough to be able to do the work needed, they can get the files to work no problem. The files end up with a unique id that is not there on other files uploaded by the site admins.

This is an example of what i mean. `/_layouts/15/download.aspx?UniqueId=%` and then an Id. None of this should be there. This is for my work so that is why the files are uploaded.

Comment: Added inline formatting. Added a paragraph break.

Comment: You can't render aspx files in SharePoint by adding them to a document library, unfortunately. Depending on what you're trying to do you could use a combination of an html file and a content editor webpart that's configured to point at the html file instead.

Comment: The issue was resolved by upgrading my permission level to Curator. Once this was done I was able to upload the files and they now render as a web page.